# Why pyspark cannot show any data?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, python-3.6, spark-streaming

when I use Windows local spark like below, it work and Can see "**df.count()**"

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Structured Streaming ") \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
    .option("subscribe", kafka_topic_name) \
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
    .load()

flower_df1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)", "timestamp")
flower_schema_string = "sepal_length DOUBLE,sepal_length DOUBLE,sepal_length DOUBLE,sepal_length DOUBLE,species STRING"
flower_df2 = flower_df1.select(from_csv(col("value"), flower_schema_string).alias("flower"), "timestamp").select("flower.*", "timestamp")
flower_df2.createOrReplaceTempView("flower_find")

song_find_text = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM flower_find")
flower_agg_write_stream = song_find_text \
    .writeStream \
    .option("truncate", "false") \
    .format("memory") \
    .outputMode("update") \
    .queryName("testedTable") \
    .start()

while True:
    df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM testedTable")
    print(df.count())

    time.sleep(1)
```

But when I use my Virtual Box's Ubuntu's Spark, NEVER SEE any data.
below is the modification I made when I using Ubuntu's Spark.

- SparkSession's master URL: "spark://192.168.15.2:7077"
- Insert code flower_agg_write_stream.awaitTermination() above "while True:"

Did I do something wrong?

ADD.
when run modification code, log appears as below:

```
...
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: testedTable;
...
```

unfortunately, I already try createOrReplaceGlobalTempView(). but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Is there any log on your code. Also share how are you running the job. i.e spark-submit params etc.

Comment: @glory9211 here is my submit command. "spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.0 kafka_stream_read.py" Do you need logs additional?

Comment: There can be a few reasons why there is no output. Can you kindly publish data on kafka while running the job (since offset is latest). Also check if you can consume data from outside spark stream on your ubuntu machine. Include a print statement with simple string inside/outside your loop to see if the code is even reaching that loop.

Comment: @glory9211 Yeah. I tried print statement all line, when i modificate the code. it stop at flower_agg_write_stream.awaitTermination(). if i don't write flower_agg_write_stream.awaitTermination(), it print log that Table or view not found: testedTable. Once, i check the offset's value! thx.